# array to xml php issue with the array(s)

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have created the function below:

```
public function arrayToXml(\SimpleXMLElement $bodyXml, array $arrayToBeConverted)
   {
       foreach ($arrayToBeConverted as $element => $value) {
           $element = ucfirst($element);
           if (is_array($value)) {
               $newXmlNode = $bodyXml->addChild($element);
               $newXmlNode = $this->arrayToXml($newXmlNode, $value);
           } else {
               $bodyXml->addChild($element, $value);
           }
       }
       $newXml = $bodyXml;
       return $newXml;
   }
 }
```

Which converts an array to xml. I am trying to create duplicates in the xml and seem to hit an issue when I use an array inside.

The following array...

```
$testArray =
[
  "Pagination" =>
  [
    "EntriesPerPage" => 2,
  ],
  ["UserId" => "Usertest1"], ["UserId" => "Usertest2"],
];
```

Outputs this section of xml

```
<pagination>
<entriesperpage>2</entriesperpage>
</pagination>
“<0>"
<userid>Usertest1</userid>
“<1>"
<userid>Usertest2</userid>
```

I basically don’t want the <0> and <1> before the userid, I understand why these indexes are there but can’t for the life of me work out a way to make this work without them. Does any array wizard have any ideas please?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
public function arrayToXml(\SimpleXMLElement $bodyXml, array $arrayToBeConverted)
{
   foreach ($arrayToBeConverted as $element => $value) {
       $element = ucfirst($element);
       if (is_array($value)) {
           $pattern = '/^\d/';

           if (!preg_match($pattern, $element)){
               $newXmlNode = $bodyXml->addChild($element);
               $newXmlNode = $this->arrayToXml($newXmlNode, $value);
           }
           else{
               $bodyXml = $this->arrayToXml($bodyXml, $value);
           }

       } else {
           $bodyXml->addChild($element, $value);
       }
   }
   $newXml = $bodyXml;
   return $newXml;
}
```

Comment: That works thank you very much. Just out of interest and to be sure I follow looking at your code, the function checks that non of the keys in $pattern exist in any element the function is attempting to add, is that correct? Is '/^\d/' how indexes will be interpreted or something? Thanks again

Comment: @JBstar Yes, you are correct. \d means digit in regular expression patterns. ^ used to define beginning of the text. So the preg_match function with the regular expression pattern '/^\d/' checks if the $element value begins with a number. If it begins with a number there is no need to add $element child in your requirements. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get something like this

```
<Pagination>
  <EntriesPerPage>2</EntriesPerPage>
</Pagination>
<UserId>Usertest1</UserId>
<UserId>Usertest2</UserId>
```

then you need to change your source array $arrayToBeConverted. It should looks like

```
$testArray =
[
    ["Pagination" => ["EntriesPerPage" => 2]],
    ["UserId" => "Usertest1"],
    ["UserId" => "Usertest2"]
];
```

and add an additional foreach

```
foreach ($arrayToBeConverted as $arrayToBeConvertedElements) {
    foreach ($arrayToBeConvertedElements as $element => $value) {
       $element = ucfirst($element);
       if (is_array($value)) {
           $newXmlNode = $bodyXml->addChild($element);
           $newXmlNode = $this->arrayToXml($newXmlNode, $value);
       } else {
           $bodyXml->addChild($element, $value);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this returns Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It can't return 'Invalid argument' if **$arrayToBeConverted** has a right format. If you want to have multiple **UserId** tags your array should be like `[0 => ["Pagination" => ["EntriesPerPage" => 2]], 1 => ["UserId" => "Usertest1"], 2 => ["UserId" => "Usertest2"]]`

Answer (score 0):

The difficulty is to know when to use the array key as an element and when not to.  Even when you use `[ 'a', 'b' ]`, these are equivalent to `[ 0=>'a', 1=>'b']`.

If you use the fact that automatically generated keys are integers (or not strings)...

```
public function arrayToXml(\SimpleXMLElement $bodyXml, array $arrayToBeConverted)
{
    foreach ($arrayToBeConverted as $element => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if ( is_string($element) )   {
                $newXmlNode = $bodyXml->addChild(ucfirst($element));
            }
            $newXml = $this->arrayToXml($newXmlNode, $value);
        } else {
            $newXml->addChild($element, $value);
        }
    }
    return $newXml;
}
```